# Ionic 2 Background Geolocation does not send ongoing position

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I am using the Background Geolocation Plugin in my Ionic 2 app.

The setup looks like this:

```
initLocation() {
    const config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
      desiredAccuracy: 10,
      stationaryRadius: 20,
      distanceFilter: 200,
      stopOnTerminate: false,
      debug: false,
      url: API_BASE_URL + '/geo_locations',
      httpHeaders: { 'Authorization': 'Token token=' + this.authentication.token }
    };

    this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config).subscribe((location) => {
      alert(location);
    });

this.initializeApp();
this.backgroundGeolocation.start();
```

When I start the app it sends the location 1-2 times to my server and then it stops. I drove around in my car (around 10km, air line) and hoped it would send an new position every 200 meters, but nothing, only once after a couple of km it sent once and update.

Any ideas what I have to change?

Comment: Which device are you trying your app?